# Dynamically set value in category.ftl

Tags: javascript, alfresco, freemarker, alfresco-share

I have a form in share with multiple fields using **category.ftl**. I want to set default values in those fields dynamically. I can set default value by passing static path of category in **share-config-custom.xml**. But now my requirement is to read values stored in one file and than set those values as default in **category.ftl**.

[image: Final Output]

For ex, On above screenshot I have set default language as English by passing English reference statically in share-config. So every time when a form renders it sets English as default language. I want this to be changed to set default language to value which is stored in file. So how to pass dynamic reference of category in share-config-custom.xml file?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant configure dynamic things in share-config-custom.xml.For that you need to workj on below things.

For each and every picker in alfresco ,alfresco share is using below javascript file.(This are YUI scripts)

1.generic-object-finder.js
2.object-finder.js

***object-finder.js*** = >
This file is generally used when type of content is authority(users of alfresco).So i think this will be not used in your case.

***generic-object-finder.js*** = >
This file is used for generic picker and using this you can set default values.

======================================================================
Below are steps to set value in picker.

**1.Alfresco.util.ComponentManager.list("Alfresco.GenericObjectFinder")**

Above method will return all object of picker , We need to pick one by one and set default value one by one in alfresco advanced search.It will return object in array form

**2. X.options.defaultValue need to be set.**
Where X will first element of **Alfresco.util.ComponentManager.list("Alfresco.GenericObjectFinder")** array

**3.x.selectItems("workspace://SpacesStore/f73a4de7-7a45-412d-ac7d-56061fcf9d76")** 
Above will set default value.You must need to pass relevant value here.